Why do Airbus engines seemingly spool up faster than Boeing?
When looking at the GP7000 and Trent XWB, their spool up times are incredibly fast. Compare this to the GE90 on the 777 which takes several seconds longer, why would this be the case? Though yes, the XWB has less thrust and is smaller than a GE90, they're relatively comparable. Compare this with a PW4000 which takes similar time to spool as a GE90 and they're even closer in size. Is this because of engine design, or something else?

Is that from the same idle setting? I bet the Airbus engines have higher idle RPM.

It's not as dependent on the aircraft as it is on the engine itself. For example, the Boeing 737 and Airbus A320 both use CFM56's as their power plant, and their spool-up times are relatively similar. Some variants of the 777 fly with the PW4000 equipped
as well with no significant difference in spool-up time. Airbus may simply have different requirements for their planes than Boeing in terms of engine performance and capabilities, but it is not strictly a manufacturer issue.
